# C++ quickly dump int array contents into text file

Tags: c++, arrays, text, int

I would like to dump the contents of a large array into a text file.  Currently, I am using fstream and for loops to accomplish this.

```
ofstream file;
file.open("vectors.csv"); 
for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
        file << array[3*i] << "," << array[3*i+1] << "," << array[3*i+2] << endl;
}
```

Array contains the x y z components of a bunch of vectors and currently they are written into a csv file delimited by a comma and endl using a for loop.  Currently this method is very time consuming as I am trying to write around 10 million vectors.  If I can insert the delimiting characters into the array, is there a faster way to dump this to an external text file?

TIA

Comment: If you need speed go for the C api equivalents `fopen` and `fprintf`

Comment: "Fast" and "as text" usually don't travel together.

Comment: I would try using `'\n'` instead of `endl`. `endl` forces a flush, which might be creating too many flushes to the disk.

Comment: Would you please say what is data type of array? is that data type fixed size? for example uinit32? -- and , are you forced to use a delimiter or you only wanna dump and read from file?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `std::endl` to write a new line as it will cause the buffer to be flushed which will significantly impact performance. 
Instead you should use either `'\n'` or `"\n"` to do so. And only use `std::endl` if you really need the buffer to be flushed.

Answer (score 2):

cout << endl  : Inserts a new line and flushes the stream.(can be an overhead depending on the use-case)

cout << "\n"  : Only inserts a new line.

for an easy explanation visit : https://cppkid.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/why-i-prefer-n-to-stdendl/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do. You can provide a large buffer to the stream, use single chars for the separator `','` and avoid `std::endl` which flushes the buffer prematurely.

```
char buffer[8096]; // larger = faster (within limits)
std::ofstream file;
file.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

file.open("vectors.csv");
for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
    // use single chars '\n'
    // use single chars ','
    file << array[3*i] << ',' << array[3*i+1] << ',' << array[3*i+2] << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my answer, I assume your array's data type is int AND you are not forced to use separators and create huaman readable CSV files. I assumed you want to dump and reload array from file as fast as possible.

Memory in array is contiguous. So you can dump and reload its data at once:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static const int SIZE = 3*100;
    //writing
    {
        std::array<int,SIZE> a;
        //....  filling array
        a[0] = 123;
        a[1] = 456;
        std::ofstream myfile ("out_array_example.bin",std::ios::binary);
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            myfile.write((const char*)(a.begin()),a.size());
            myfile.close();
        }
    }
    //////////////////////
    //reading
    {
        std::ifstream file("out_array_example.bin", std::ios::binary);
        std::array<int,SIZE> a;
        if (file.read((char*)a.begin(), SIZE))
        {
            std::cout << "Now my array is reloaded:" << a[0] << " , " << a[1] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```